# C# Xamarin: Working code throws NullReferenceException when called from DLL

Tags: c#, xamarin

so I have this code segment, it creates an integer control for my Xamarin form with an accompaning + and - button. This works like a charm when I put it directly in my Xamarin form. But as soon as I put it into a class in a DLL for reusing, I get NullReferenceException, when clicking "plus" or "minus". There's no way to catch this Exception or handle any null case (as you see in plusClicked I tried), the NullReferenceException seems to be happening in a space out of my control.

```
        public View createIntegerControl(String name, String value, int DatabaseId = 0)
    {
        StackLayout newStackLayout = new StackLayout();
        newStackLayout.SetValue(AttachableProperties.DatabaseIdProperty, DatabaseId);

        Label label = new Label();
        label.Text = name;

        Grid inputFields = new Grid();

        ColumnDefinition col1 = new ColumnDefinition();
        ColumnDefinition col2 = new ColumnDefinition();
        ColumnDefinition col3 = new ColumnDefinition();

        GridLength gridLengthEntry = new GridLength(70, GridUnitType.Star);
        GridLength gridLengthButton = new GridLength(15, GridUnitType.Star);

        col1.Width = gridLengthEntry;
        col2.Width = gridLengthButton;
        col3.Width = gridLengthButton;

        inputFields.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col1);
        inputFields.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col2);
        inputFields.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col3);

        Entry entry = new Entry();
        entry.Text = value;
        entry.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);

        Button plus = new Button();
        plus.Text = "+";
        plus.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);
        plus.Clicked += plusClicked;

        Button minus = new Button();
        minus.Text = "-";
        minus.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 2);
        minus.Clicked += minusClicked;

        newStackLayout.Children.Add(label);
        inputFields.Children.Add(entry);
        inputFields.Children.Add(plus);
        inputFields.Children.Add(minus);
        newStackLayout.Children.Add(inputFields);

        return newStackLayout;
    }

public static void plusClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (sender != null)
            {
                Button button = (Button)sender;
                if (button.Parent != null)
                {
                    Grid grid = (Grid)button.Parent;

                    if (grid.Parent != null)
                    {
                        if (grid.Children.Count > 0)
                        {
                            Entry entry = (Entry)grid.Children[0];
                            entry.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(entry.Text) + 1).ToString();
                        }
                        else Console.WriteLine("no children for grid");
                    }
                    else Console.WriteLine("no grid parent");
                }
                else Console.WriteLine("no button parent");
            }
            else Console.WriteLine("no sender");
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception");
        }
    }

    public void minusClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender != null)
        {
            Button button = (Button)sender;
            Grid grid = (Grid)button.Parent;
            Entry entry = (Entry)grid.Children[0];
            entry.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(entry.Text) - 1).ToString();
        }
    }
```

Additional data from the worker thread

```
    Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper._unhandled_exception(System.TypeLoadException e) Line 12
Nicht markiert  >   1   0   Arbeitsthread       Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper._unhandled_exception(System.TypeLoadException e) Line 12
0xE in Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper._unhandled_exception at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:12,5
0x1E in Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPL_V at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:111,26
0x11 in Xamarin.Forms.Button.Xamarin.Forms.Internals.IButtonElement.PropagateUpClicked at D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Button.cs:187,47
0x20 in Xamarin.Forms.ButtonElement.ElementClicked at D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\ButtonElement.cs:61,5
0x2 in Xamarin.Forms.Button.SendClicked at D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Button.cs:173,32
0x4 in Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ButtonElementManager.OnClick at D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\ButtonElementManager.cs:25,4
0xD in Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FastRenderers.ButtonRenderer.Android.Views.View.IOnClickListener.OnClick at D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\FastRenderers\ButtonRenderer.cs:72,45
0x11 in Android.Views.View.IOnClickListenerInvoker.n_OnClick_Landroid_view_View_ at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/monoandroid10/android-31/mcw/Android.Views.View.cs:2280,5
0x9 in Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPL_V at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:110
```

Comment: _" the NullReferenceException seems to be happening in a space out of my control."_ Got a stacktrace?

Comment: Unfortunately no, there's no stacktrace shown.

Comment: In Visual Studio, go to Tools->Options->Debugging and disable "just my code". That should give you a better error report when you get the exception again.

Comment: Managed to get a bit of data from the worker thread and put it into the description, sorry for the few german words

Comment: Not entirely sure, but **probably** the issue comes from the assignation of the event listeners for your button; try making them non-static and referencing them with `this` i.e. `plus.Clicked += this.plusClicked;`

Comment: The other thing that ocurs to me is that the calling project is missing a reference

Comment: So I've tried everything up and down and reached a state I kind of will live with. While it is perfectly possible to define the controls in a library, the plusClicked and minusClicked will only work if they're defined in the form that uses it, so I pass those EventHandlers as parameters to the function. I assume this might be due to the form containing the controls after creation owning them, thus not allowing outside event handling, but I'm guessing at this point. It would be nice if someone could confirm or deny my assumptions and explain what happened here.

Comment: Could you please help create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) via github repo?

Answer (score 0):

While I don't think it is the problem (given that the code works when directly in your main project), fix your null-checks:

```cs
// If isn't a button, result is null.
Button button = sender as Button;
if (button != null)
{
    // If isn't a grid, result is null.
    Grid grid = button.Parent as Grid;
    if (grid != null)
    {
        ...
        // If isn't an Entry, result is null.
        Entry entry = grid.Children[0] as Entry;
        if (entry != null)
        {
```